# Arraylist from text file

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an `ArrayList` from data like this taken from a text file called `price.txt`. So the `A` and the `B` are the region codes, the integers are the weight in kilos and the double is the price.

```
A

15  3.50

25  4.50

35  6.70

50  7.20


B

15  4.70

25  7.20

35  8.60

50  10.50
```

I've created an object to hold the data.

```
public class CostList {
    private String code; //Holds Region code
    private double weight; //Holds weight
    private double price; //Holds price
}
```

But I'm having trouble getting my head around reading it from the text file and then inputting from the text file.

Comment: Show us what you did ... we are not going to do it for you

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Are you unsure of how to read from a file? (Search up BufferedReader and BufferedWriter) Or are you unsure how to seperate the second line into one integer and one double? (View StringTokenizer, Double.parseDouble() and Integer.parseInt()) Or is it the logic behind processing this information?

Comment: Unless you know more advanced `io`, use `Scanner` class for reading.

Comment: This is not clear, could you edit and add an example of a `CostList` you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better you have an object structure like this (names chosen by myself):

```
public class Item {
   private double weight; //Holds weight
   private double price; //Holds price
}
```

and

```
public class Region{
   private String name; //Holds region name
   private List<Item> items; //Holds different items for the region (lines in your file)
}
```

With your solution you have to create for every line an object with the same region, now you have one object for each region, and inside a list with items for this region!

Concerning the file read I would recommend to look at some tutorials like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html). You can easily search in google for reading files in java and you will find a lot of different pages with help! 
If you have trouble with the process you can ask here, but first try for yourself to implement the file - read - operation!